# PHP Unit / Mockery - Mock static function not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Hey so I have the below method and when trying to mock the Manager::getConfiguration call, I cannot get it to work. I have tried using a namedMock as well as the unit test decorators to have it run in another thread. It either gives me a class already exists error or actually pulls the manager configuration which I do not want.

```
public function getBaseTypeManagerConfig() {
        $baseTypeManagerConfig = array();

        if (!empty($this->dataConfig)
                && !empty($baseType = $this->dataConfig->getBaseType())) {
            $baseTypeManagerConfig = Manager::getConfiguration($baseType);
        }

        return $baseTypeManagerConfig;
}

/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
public function testBaseTypeManagerConfig() {
         $managerMock = Mockery::namedMock('Manager', 'ManagerStub');
         $managerMock->shouldReceive('getConfiguration')->andReturn(self::MOCKED_MANAGER_DECODED_JSON);

         $listModule = Mockery::mock('GenericListModule')->makePartial();
         $listModule->shouldReceive([
                 'getBaseType' => 'events',
         ]);

         $config = \SWL\Lib\Generic\ConfigFactory::getConfig('Events_Event');
         $listModule->shouldReceive('setDataConfig')->andSet('dataConfig', $config);

         $baseTypeManagerConfig = $listModule->getBaseTypeManagerConfig();
         $this->assertEquals(array(), $baseTypeManagerConfig);
}

// Attempt at using named mock to replace 'Manager' class with mock
class ManagerStub {
    public static function getConfiguration($configType) {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why I can't use this named mock to replace the Manager call? New to unit testing and phpunit/mockery so any other pointers welcome. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question and welcome to Stackoverflow.

> Any thoughts on why I can't use this named mock to replace the Manager call? New to unit testing and phpunit/mockery so any other pointers welcome. Thank you! :)

This is perhaps less the question about the testing framework and the mocking library but better answered by the language in question, here PHP, but it may also apply to other languages similarly.

Given a call to a static method like:

> ```php
> $baseTypeManagerConfig = Manager::getConfiguration($baseType);
> ```

there is nothing that can be dynamically replaced because `Manager::getConfiguration` is static.

- [Static Methods - Static Keyword - Classes and Objects (PHP Manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods)

As this is so common, why does it appear as a problem for *mocking* specifically while writing a test for such code?

As a class can only exist once (by its name not a constraint for aliasing, e.g. the same class with one or more different names) that specific method can as well only be defined once.

With a generic mocking framework (mock builder, stub builder etc.), a problem can arise. While it's possible to create a mock of the manager class:

```
Manager -> ManagerMock
```

The code under test does not magically change to it, e.g. like this:

```php
$baseTypeManagerConfig = ManagerMock::getConfiguration($baseType);
```

But stays the same:

```php
$baseTypeManagerConfig = Manager::getConfiguration($baseType);
```

And therefore knows nothing about the mock.

This might appear that you can't mock `Manager`, however it is just that `Manager` is in the global static state and it remained unchanged. The mock of `Manager` was added to it, however it is of no use to execute the code under test for your testing purposes.

So far, so good. Embrace this for a moment.

---

One common answer to this kind of problem is to make `Manager` inject able.

This could be by a *test-point*, e.g. having a specific `Manager` class only in testing that allows you to inspect deep for assertions.

This could also be with dependency injection, that is injecting the `Manager` as a dependency, for example when creating the object as a parameter of its constructor.

```php
public function getBaseTypeManagerConfig() {
        $baseTypeManagerConfig = array();

        if (!empty($this->dataConfig)
                && !empty($baseType = $this->dataConfig->getBaseType())) {
            $configurationGettingFunction = $this->configurationGettingFunction;
            $baseTypeManagerConfig = $configurationGettingFunction($baseType);
        }

        return $baseTypeManagerConfig;
}
```

It turns the hidden dependency of `Manager::getBaseTypeManagerConfig` into a visible and inject able one.

In tests then, when creating the Subject Under Test (SUT), you inject the "mocked" function instead of the static one.

This also makes visible which collaborators the SUT needs to do its work. Your tests cover that refactoring.

This should be easy to do.

Mind thought that this adds a layer of indirection. While it perhaps might be worth to consider that it is beneficial to your design, it may also not be.

Therefore one might decide that the indirection is unwanted and `Manager::getConfiguration` should remain static, and the static method call use is intended (by design).

Then it should be able to represent test-able configuration, so while it remains static, it is capable to address the configuration needs in at least both environments: developing and testing.

The developing environment is just the default one, your code exists and executes.

The testing environment is the one when you test the code, e.g. within unit-tests.

Regardless how you solve it in the end, these two environments you'll always find when writing tests.

And only code that is compatible with the testing environment can be tested.

So what you aim for is that your code in general is test-able (and with as little mocks and stubs, that is code you write only for testing and then you most of all test your mocks and stubs and less the code you want to test).

This is often also how when starting to write tests for the code, this reveals design issues showing places where the code might not be portable for different environments. This can:

- Reveal missing configuration capabilities (e.g. make the code work as intended by injecting the data (parameters) as needed)
- Reveal higher level design issues (e.g. functions and classes can not be used flexible enough to work as intended)

The important part here is that you, as you write the tests and the code understand where the issue stems from that makes it hard for you to write the test.

So first of all realizing that there is not a technical issue foremost (why does the mocking library not support feature xyz?) but to understand the code under test (what is it actually doing here? is that my intention?).

Only the later part will allow you to change the code and develop further and to obtain the benefit from writing the test.

Otherwise you would write a test just to write one and get it pass. Not much use of that. And totally easy with an extension that is able to actually overwrite `Manager::getConfiguration` - *Uopz* or *Componere*.

However, treat it as non technical issue here, and instead as a design problem with your code. Why? Because you gain more benefit from testing, and your code is to be changed. Now and in future. Testing allows you to see these change requirements in a reproducible manner now and, not only for now, but also ahead of time when you start to write tests.

Use the tests to define how the code should work. Not to create mocks.

And if you allow me a personal comment: I hate to write mocks in testing. It starts to become cumbersome pretty early even for code for which mocks technically can work. Therefore I often take a look how the code can be simplified so that it can be used more easily. As then it can be also tested more easily.

Comment: Hey Hakre, thanks so much for the response - this was really helpful. I am working in a large system and trying out TDD (we currently have no unit tests). This post was helpful to get me to pause and consider what am I actually needing to test etc and think about larger design decisions across the product vs getting too focused on a single test.

Comment: @harrisonlucas: If it answered your question, you can give it a green checkmark. And if it was helpful, give it an upvote. And welcome to Stackoverflow again. Great to read it gave you good pointers. And happy testing!

Comment: And thinking of your comment, if you want a good read at hand, it perhaps is Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers. When the code is already done, you want to specifically know where to introduce unit-tests and what for. And you want to know about the boundaries. IMHO this book can inspire to some very useful thoughts and practices.

Comment: Okay great I will definitely check that book out - thanks again for all the help!